ExchangeTransactionContract in blockchain Tron
I'm learning about transaction types in the Tron blockchain.
I need to understand how different transaction types affect the TRX address balance.
Everything was fine until I came across ExchangeTransactionContract.
I need to calculate how much TRX was received or sent in an exchange and preferably do it through a node (if possible).
I found 3 url's that help me a little bit, but don't solve the problem:

wallet/getassetissuebyid
Allows me to get me the balances of a couple, but as I understand it, it's the balance now, not at any particular moment

wallet/getexchangebyid
Allows me to get the token information

wallet/gettransactionbyid
Get the transaction from the node.


The whole problem is that 3) option returns 2 important fields

quant
expected

But the final TRX value when exchanging token for TRX is almost always different from expected. And how to calculate it - I don't know.
Also I found information in Tron documentation, where they talk about Bancor protocol, but they don't have any information about token exchange in Tron network.

The developers of Tron were able to answer my question. And I also supplemented the answer with a working example in Python.
Here is the issue itself
